# Evaluate JSON object with expression with variable name, Josson

Tags: java, json, spring, extjs

We need to evaluate JSON object expressions in java.

We have the following source JSON object

```js
{
  "a": 100,
  "b": 200,
  "c": 300,
  "d": "calc(a+c)",
  "f": {
    "g": 100,
    "h": 200,
    "i": "calc(g+h)"
  }
}
```

we need output this format

```js
{
  "a": 100,
  "b": 200,
  "c": 300,
  "d": 400,
   "f": {
    "g": 100,
    "h": 200,
    "i": 300
  }
}
```

We tried

we tried https://github.com/octomix/josson but that is more of a filtering JSON.

Comment: How is this an extjs question?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps. All the necessary information is mentioned inside the code itself.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String inputString = "{'a': 100, 'b': 200, 'c': 300, 'd': 'calc(a+c)', 'f': {'g': 100, 'h': 200, 'i': 'calc(g+h)'} }";

        JSONObject newJSON = parseJSONValue(inputString, new JSONObject());

        System.out.println(newJSON.toString());
        // {"a":100,"b":200,"c":300,"d":400,"f":{"g":100,"h":200,"i":300}}

    }

    public static JSONObject parseJSONValue(String inputString, JSONObject resultJSON) {

        // Parse your string as JSONObject
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(inputString);
        Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();

        // Iterate through your keys
        while (keys.hasNext()) {

            String key = keys.next();
            Object value = jsonObject.get(key);

            if (value instanceof Integer) {

                // Your normal values

            } else if (value instanceof String) {

                // Your 'calc(x+y)' strings

                // Extract everything between "(" and ")" from calc(a+c)
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)");
                Matcher m = pattern.matcher(value.toString());

                while (m.find()) {

                    // a+c
                    String evalString = m.group(1);

                    // Split by '+'
                    String[] splitEvalString = evalString.split("\\+");

                    // Check if exactly 2 values are found
                    if (splitEvalString.length == 2) {
                        value = (Integer) jsonObject.get(splitEvalString[0])
                                + (Integer) jsonObject.get(splitEvalString[1]);
                    }

                }

            } else if (value instanceof JSONObject) {
                // Your nested JSONObjects
                // Recursively call this method
                value = parseJSONValue(value.toString(), new JSONObject());
            }

            // Add to your new JSON Object
            resultJSON.put(key, value);

        }

        return resultJSON;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(jsonString);
JsonNode node = josson.getNode("field(d:eval(d), f.field(i:eval(i)))");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

*Output*

```
{
  "a" : 100,
  "b" : 200,
  "c" : 300,
  "d" : 400.0,
  "f" : {
    "g" : 100,
    "h" : 200,
    "i" : 300.0
  }
}
```

**For unknown structure**

*This solution assumes*

- the evaluation statement contains `()`
- there is only one evaluation statement in each level
- you need to know the next level child name (`f` in this example)

*Transformation*

```
JsonNode node = josson.getNode(
    "let($p: '.+\\(.*\\).*')" +
    ".field(entries().[value =~ $p].key :: eval(*[value =~ $p])," +
    "       f.field(entries().[value =~ $p].key :: eval(*[value =~ $p]))" +
    ")");
```

**Suggest to group all the expressions in a pre-defined array**

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "  \"a\": 100," +
    "  \"b\": 200," +
    "  \"c\": 300," +
    "  \"f\": {" +
    "    \"g\": 100," +
    "    \"h\": 200" +
    "  }," +
    "  \"exp\": [\"$.calc(a+c)\"," +
    "            \"$.calc(g+h, g:f.g, h:f.h)\"," +
    "            \"$.concat(a, '+', c, '=', calc(a+c))\"," +
    "            \"$.concat(f.g, '+', f.h, '=', calc(g+h, g:f.g, h:f.h))\"" +
    "           ]" +
    "}");
JsonNode node = josson.getNode("field(exp@.eval())");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

*Output*

```
{
  "a" : 100,
  "b" : 200,
  "c" : 300,
  "f" : {
    "g" : 100,
    "h" : 200
  },
  "exp" : [ 400.0, 300.0, "100+300=400.0", "100+200=300.0" ]
}
```

Comment: Hello @Raymond, Thanks for the answer. This solves the issue where we know the json structure. But can you suggest more generic way where the json structure is not known and json can be iterated and eval can be done wherever some formuala like calc, concat is used. Also maintain the depth of json

Comment: I'm the author of Josson.  Currently, function `findAndModify()` only support array. I'm thinking of enhancing the function to support object too. It will be available in the next version.

Comment: Added a suggestion